# PHP Error Handling during form Validation

Tags: javascript, php

I have designed a web page. First user should enter his email-id and then only password page appears. I wanted to display an error in the email page if the email-id entered by the user is not in my database (csv file).

Following is the php code:

```
function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
  $email = clean_text($_GET['email']);
  $file = fopen('info.csv','r');
  while (! feof($file)){
    if ($csv_line = fgetcsv($file)){
      if ($csv_line[0] == $email){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        header('Location: password.php');
      }
    }
  }
  if (feof($file)){
    $error = "No account, you can create one";
  }
  fclose($file);
}
```

Following is the HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #container-primary{
    background-color: ;
  }
  #container-secondary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #container-tertiary{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  #email{
    width: 80%;
  }
  #email-form{
  }
  #email-error-container{
    background-color: ;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  #button-container1{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  #button-container2{
    background-color: ;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #submit-button{
    width: 90px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="function1()">
  <div class="container mt-5 pt-2 pb-4" id="container-primary">
    <div class="container mt-3" id="container-secondary"><h3>Welcome</h3><br> Please Enter your Email to continue</br>
    </div>
    <div class="container pt-2" id="container-tertiary">
      <form method="get" id="email-form" autocomplete="off">
          <input type="text" class="form-control mx-auto" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" spellcheck="false"></input>
        <div class="container text-danger" id="email-error-container">
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="button-container1">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" disabled value="Next" id="submit-button" onclick="click_email()" name="submit"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="container mt-2" id="button-container1">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="No Account?" id="create-account-button" name="create-account"></input>
       </div>
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $("#email").focus();
        var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        $("#email").on('input', function(){
          if (document.getElementById("email").value.match(mailformat)){
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = false;
          }
          else{
            document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
          }
        })
      })
     $(document).ready(function(){
       var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
       $("#email").blur(function(){
         if (document.getElementById('email').value.match(mailformat)){
         }
         else{
           if (document.getElementById('email').value.length >=1){
             document.getElementById("email-error-container").className = "container text-danger";
             document.getElementById("email-error-container").innerHTML = "<strong>**Please Enter Valid Email Id</strong>";
             setTimeout(function () {
               $("#email-error-container").empty();
             }, 1000);
           }
         }
       })
     })
    </script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#submit-button').click(function(){
           var email_error = <?php echo $error ?>;
           if (email_error != ''){
             document.getElementById("email-error-container").className = "container text-danger";
             document.getElementById("email-error-container").innerHTML = email_error;
             setTimeout(function () {
               $("#email-error-container").empty();
             }, 1000);
           }
         })
       })
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){if(e.keyIdentifier=='U+000A'||e.keyIdentifier=='Enter'||e.keyCode==13){if(e.target.nodeName=='INPUT'&&e.target.type=='text'){e.preventDefault();return false;}}},true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Explanation of code:

1. HTML and JS is written in such a way that, if the user enters a text which is not in the format of an email, the submit button will be disabled and will be enabled only if the text is in the format of an email. User will also be notified that the text is not in the format of an email as an error message in a div container right below the email input field.
2. Once the user enters valid email, php checks whether the email is in my database (`info.csv`).

If the email id is not in my database, there should be an error message in the same div container as `'No account, you can create one'`. 
 which I have done using JavaScript. (last but one code in `<script></script>`)

Problem is when the user enters a valid email-id which is not in my database, he is not getting the error.
`"No account, your can create one"`.